# Laravel Datatables search on nested Relationship

Tags: laravel, datatables

I'm currently using datatabels 7.0 and Laravel 5.4
data in my grid is showing correctly but when I want to search on nested relationship column I got below error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'course_semester.semester.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `videos` where LOWER(`videos`.`id`) LIKE %%te%% and LOWER(`videos`.`name`) LIKE %%te%% and LOWER(`course_semester`.`semester`.`name`) LIKE %%te%%) count_row_table)
```

Here is my code

Controller

```
$videos = Video::with(['course_semester' => function ($query) {
            return $query->with('course', 'semester');
        }])->select('videos.*');
        return Datatables::of($videos)
                ->addColumn('check', '<input type="checkbox" name="selected-videos" value="{{$id}}">')
                ->escapeColumns([])
                ->make(true);
```

Javascript

```
columns: [
                 { data: 'check' , name: 'check',orderable: false, searchable: false },
                 { data: 'id', name: 'videos.id' },
                 { data: 'name', name: 'videos.name' },
                 { data: 'course_semester.semester.name', name: 'course_semester.semester.name'},
                 { data: 'course_semester.course.name', name: 'course_semester.course.name'},
                 { data: 'status', name: 'videos.status' },
                 { data: 'comment', name: 'videos.comment' },
                 { data: 'video_date', name: 'videos.video_date' },
            ]
```

Can anyone help me and notice my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of using `select()` here, you do not load the relationship. Also, use dot syntax for [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$videos = Video::with(['course_semester', 'course_semester.course'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , but the yajrabox datatable documantation says  [EloquentController.php - Eloquent Datatable with Eager Loading](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/relationships)

Comment: @HamedYarandi in the docs they're not using nested eager loading and you do.

Comment: With your suggestion I got this error : `No available engine for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`

Comment: @HamedYarandi I didn't use the datatables package, but it looks like you need to remove `get()` part.

Answer (score 6):

1- dataTable function

```
public function dataTable($query)
{
    return datatables()
        ->eloquent($query)
        ->addColumn('BulkSelection', function ($category) 
        {
        ->addColumn('company', function ($category) 
        {
            return $category->company ? $category->company->name : 'No Company';
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action', 'company', 'createdAt','BulkSelection']);
}
```

2- query function

```
    public function query(Category $model)
{
        return $model->with('company:id,name')->select('categories.*')->newQuery();
}
```

3- getColumns function

```
$getCols = [
     
        'id',
        'name',
        'company'=> [
            'data'=>'company',
            'name'=>'company.name'
        ],
        'createdAt' => [
            'name'=>'created_at',
            'searchable' => false
        ],
        'action' => [
            'exportable' => false,
            'searchable'=>false,
            'orderable' => false
        ]
    ];

    return $getCols;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to load the data from relation tables, use the below code

```
$videos = Video::with('course_semester','course', 'semester')->select('videos.*');
        return Datatables::eloquent($videos)
                ->addColumn('check', function(Video $v){ 
                  return '<input type="checkbox" name="selected-videos" value="{{$v->id}}">'
                  })
                ->rawColumns(['check'])
                ->make(true);
```

And in script, you can call relation values as ,

```
          {data: 'course_semester.id'},
          {data: 'course.name'},
          {data: 'semester.name'},
```

Comment: But this returns column videos.course not found if searched on no related course collection were found

Answer (score 2):

```
 $getCols = [
           
         
            'title',
            'Images' => [
                'name'=>'images_count',
                'data'=>'images_count',
                'searchable'=>false
            ],
            'price' => ['name'=>'start_price', 'data'=>'start_price'],
            'reserve_price',
            'Category' => [
                'data'=>'show_category',
                'name'=>'categories.name',
                'searchable'=>false
            ],
            'created_by' => [
                'name'=>'user.name',
            ],
            'createdAt' => [
                'name'=>'created_at',
                'searchable' => false
            ],
            'action' => [
                'exportable' => false,
                'searchable'=>false,
                'orderable' => false
            ]
```

Comment: Maybe would be nice some explanation of your answer suggestion